# Find $2\times2$ matrices, $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A\ne0$, $C\ne{B}$, but $AC=AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question I have is:

Find $2\times2$ matrices, $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $A\ne0$, $C\ne B$, but $AC=AB$.

I cant figure out where to start on this question. I tried the following things:

1. I looked up a list of the properties of matrix operations to see if I could find any relevant ones that would help me tackle this problem:
   http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/54summer10/matalg.pdf

Some  properties look potentially helpful/applicable like:
$A(BC)=(AB)C$ and $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I_n$. But i'm not sure how to apply those.

2. I tried letting $A=I_2$, but if $A=I_2$ and $AC=AB$, then wouldn't $C=B$ which isn't allowed?

Comment: If $AB=AC$ and $A$ is invertible, then you could multiply both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$ to conclude that $B=C$.  Therefore, you need to use an $A$ that does not have an inverse.  I suggest taking $A$ to be the matrix with a $1$ in the top left corner and zeros everywhere else.

Comment: Write $D = C-B$. The problem is transformed into: Find two non-zero matrices $A$ and $D$ so that $AD=0$. (Obviously, this is a special case of the original problem: put $C=D$ and $B=0$.) Can you solve it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1&0 \\ 0&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&d\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ 0&0\end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

yes you are right, just think of easy solution you will surely get one of your own.

$A= \left[\begin{array}{l}1&-1\\1&-1\end{array}\right] $, $B= \left[\begin{array}{l}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right] $, $C= \left[\begin{array}{l}2&2\\2&2\end{array}\right] $

Answer (score 1):

Take$$A=B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }C=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Then$$AB=AC=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$